# can't extract module's Version DXL IBM DOORS

Tags: ibm-doors, readxl

I'm working on a DXL program in Doors which supposed to output to a csv file all of source module, target, linkset and version of each (source/target) modules. I've succeed to output "source module, target, linkset but I couldn't extract the version of modules. Does anyone know how to do it ?

Here is my code bellow:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Please avoid posting code as images. It will be much easier for others to help if it is entered as text

Answer (score 0):

The following uses an output file which is in C:\Temp, but you can easily change that.
it works by matching modules using a grep string, again which you can change to suit.
I have different module types, and therefore I can just get the results on the prefix 'STR' in this case.  I decided to have multiple scripts for different prefix modules, rather than dynamically pass the STR keyword.

You need to enter your folder and subfolders for the "modPathname"
then adjust the Regexp "GrepString" to suit your naming convention
alternatively you can bypass all this by hardcoding the values.

```
string      filename          = "C:\\TEMP\\STR_Baseline_Info.txt"
Stream      outFile           = write filename
string      Modtype           = "STR"


void PrintAndOutput ( string s)
{
    // print (s)    // Enable if you want output 
    outFile << s
}


void DisplayResults( string Modtype )
{


    Item        modItem
    Module      mName
    Regexp      GrepString        = regexp2 "^" Modtype "-[0-8][0-9][0-9]"
    Folder      modPathname       = folder "/EnterYourFolderHere/AnySubFolders/" Modtype ""
    string      fullModuleName , CommentStr , moduleName
    Baseline    b



    PrintAndOutput  "------------------------------------------------------------------------------\n"     
    CommentStr = "This File is automatically produced via the " Modtype " Baseline Info.dxl script.  \n" Modtype " Versions as of :  " dateAndTime(today)   "\n"
    PrintAndOutput CommentStr
    PrintAndOutput  "-------------------------------------------------------------------------------\n\n"       

    for modItem in modPathname do
    {
        if  (type (modItem ) == "Formal") 
        {
            moduleName = (name modItem)

            if (GrepString moduleName)
            {

                fullModuleName = (fullName(modItem))
                mName =  read(fullName modItem , false)

                b= getMostRecentBaseline (mName)

                if (b != null )
                {
                   PrintAndOutput  moduleName  "      -\tBaseline : "(major b)"."(minor b)(suffix b) "   \t " (dateOf b) "\n"
                }
                else
                {
                    PrintAndOutput  moduleName "       \t### No Baseline Information ### \t"  " \n"
                }
            }

        }
    }
}


DisplayResults ( Modtype)
```